# Passing Arguments in Navigation, still receiving null in ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguements

Tags: flutter, null

A. Navigating from sourceScreen to the Detailscreen with {dataValue}

Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/detailScreenRoute', arguments: "souceScreendata");

B.
In DetailScreen, **Modal Routes are null**

```
class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      final arguments = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguements;
      print(arguments); //  Issue:: receiving null instead of values

      return Scaffold(
        body: Container(),
      );
  }
```

C. Attaching App class too from main.dart

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      locale: context.locale,
      title: Strings.appName,
      theme: CustomTheme.lightTheme,
      onGenerateRoute: AppRoutes.generateRoute,
      home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
```

Arguments passing and receiving.

Answer (score 1):

The `onGenerateRoute` approach is different from passing arguments directly to the route. You should manage arguments directly inside `onGenerateRoute`: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments#alternatively-extract-the-arguments-using-ongenerateroute

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguements;
```

It's a typo: arguements, instead of arguments.